# Trial amounts in Charge

Tags: plugin-charge

So a client is setting up a subscription website. It has an initial payment of $10, and then $0.99 monthly. Has anyone gotten trial amounts to work? I basically need to charge them $10 then set up a subscription. I'm trying to figure out a way to make it seamless for the user.

There's no way to make a charge programmatically via Charge without writing a second plugin. I know this is doable via vanilla Stripe, but I'd like to use Charge for all the convenient features.

Any ideas?